# Search Bar needs double click before cursor appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, searchbar

What do I have to change in the code to get the cursor appear in the search bar after one click instead of a double click? Or why the placeholder does not disappear after one click into the field? (The basic idea of the value and placeholder should stay this way).

**HTML**

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="searchbox" placeholder="" value="Suche..." maxlength="99" autocomplete ="off" onMouseDown="active();" onBlur="inactive();"/>
    <button id="searchbutton"> Los!</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function active(){
    var searchbox = document.getElementById('searchbox');
    if(searchbox.value == 'Suche...'){
        searchbox.value = ''
        searchbox.placeholder = 'Suche...'         
    }
}

function inactive(){
    var searchbox = document.getElementById('searchbox');

    if(searchbox.value == ''){
        searchbox.value = 'Suche...'
        searchbox.placeholder = ''   
     }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're expecting here...it seems to work with only 1 click for me. https://jsfiddle.net/2844uL3r/

Comment: yes you a right, but not with firefox..:/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use all that code to make a placeholder. You just need this:

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="searchbox" placeholder="Suche..." maxlength="99" autocomplete ="off">
    <button id="searchbutton"> Los!</button>
</form>
```

And it will work. If you use the placeholder tag, when you click on it and start typing it the text will dissapear, you don't need JavaScript code for that.

And one more thing... that code is not "jQuery" code, it's just JavaScript code.

To change the placeholder color use CSS:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: black;
  }

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
     color: black;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
     color: black;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
     color: black;  
}
```

Comment: I know that it will work like this, but it's not the same like in my version with the variable "Suche..." written in black. You know what I mean? And thanks for the advice :)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do. You mean you want the placeholder to have a black color instead of the default grey? Then change it with CSS.

Comment: okay, at first it's a really petty problem (it makes only a little difference), but still I want to know why I need a double click instead of one click. 
What I want to do: When you go to the site, in the search bar there is the word "Suche..." in black letters. when you click inside the black letters (the variable) changes to the grey letters (placeholder) and when I type something in the placeholder disappears. I know it is maybe too much of detail, but still wanna know why it needs a double click before i can type words in it^^ Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: What browser are you using? Because I am using Chrome and I only have to do one click to use focus the input bar.

Comment: Wow you are right!...I am using Firefox..Hm something of the code causes trouble in Firefox